# Affect of blocksizes of images and their overviews on the rendering performance of GeoTIFFs

Tags: geotiff-tiff

I have a GeoTIFF with the following dimensions.

```
size 67200, 73600

Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Palette
  Overviews: 33600x36800, 16800x18400, 8400x9200, 4200x4600
```

How would changing the blocksize of the overviews affect the rendering performance of the image?

Comment: This question may help: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27160/geotiff-format-tile-and-overview-confusion

Comment: I am aware of the uses of tiles and overviews. My question is really asking whether I can optimize performance by changing the blocksize during the creation of the GeoTIFF. would blocksizes of 512 x 512 or 1024 x 1024 be better in some situations? Could I create 256 x 2048 and when could that be useful?

Comment: As you can guess, the optimal tile size depends on the use case. It the whole image must be processed striped tiff may be better than tiled. Your use case is rendering and then tiles are usually essential. The optimal tile size depends. If you really need just one pixel (the height of DEM at a point) then small tile size is good. For larger areas if tiles as small the system needs to read less unnecessary pixels at the borders of BBOX, but on the other hand the system must find more tiles from the tiff index and from the file system. You know your environment, make well planned tests.